# How to apply percent error to list of data

Tags: list-manipulation, warning-messages

Say I have a list of data.  `data = {1,2,3,4,5}` and those data values were measured with an instrument that has a listed 3% error.  I can apply this per value with code:`Around[1,Scaled[Quantity[3,"Percent"]]]`
.  How would I apply this to the whole list that may be a few hundred data points long?

Comment: `Around[#,Scaled[Quantity[3,"Percent"]]] & /@ list`?

Comment: Also directly Around[list, Scaled[Quantity[3, "Percent"]]].

Comment: Simple alternative `Around[list, .03]`

Comment: Thanks for the help!